# How to use the phrase "let alone" in this situation?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

Context: X is a superior fighter to Y. X didn't beat Z in a boxing match.

I want to make a statement meaning Y is even less likely to beat Z, using the phrase "let alone". How can I do it?

1. X didn't beat Z, let alone Y.
2. Z wasn't beat by X, let alone Y.

I don't think sentence 1 means what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Note that OP's #2 should be *Z wasn't **beaten** by X, let alone Y.*

Both versions are in principle ambiguous (maybe Y is less likely than X *to beat* Z, OR maybe Y is less likely than Z *to be beaten by* X. You can disambiguate by putting ***even*** before the one that Y is less likely to apply to...

> ***Even** X didn't beat Z, let alone Y*
> *Z wasn't beaten by **even** X, let alone Y*

...which both unambiguously assert that Y is far less likely to beat Z than X is (likely to beat Z). And given that (even) X *didn't* beat Z, the chance of Y beating Z is *extremely* low.

---

Note that OP's second example can also be disambiguated by repeating the preposition...

> 2a: *Z wasn't beaten by X, let alone **by** Y*
> Y is even less likely than X to win
> ...WHICH IS **NOT** THE SAME AS...
> Y is even less likely to be beaten by X than Z is (likely to be beaten by X)

---

It may help people see the ambiguity if they imagine saying OP's example sentences with very heavy stress on ***either X OR Z***. Whichever one you put the heavy stress on (and/or precede by ***even*** is the one that ***let alone Y*** applies to.

> **X** didn't beat Z, let alone Y
> (if **even X** couldn't beat Z, Y would have no chance of beating Z)
> **Z** wasn't beaten by X, let alone Y
> (if X couldn't beat **even Z**, X would have no chance of beating Y)

Comment: This is so extremely confusing I'm not even sure what you are trying to say, and I doubt the asker is either.   Neither of your two examples are natural English and their usage is nearly nonexistent (as I verified in multiple copora).   No one should form sentences like these if they wish to sound natural or be understood.

Comment: Do you in fact understand the *starting* point here? (That both the OP's examples are ambiguous, so arguably we can say they *both* mean what he wants, or that *neither* of them do. If you don't grasp the ambiguity in the first place, you're never gonna make sense of the question.

Comment: There's no ambiguity.  Both examples in OP convey the same meaning but are somewhat unnatural.   Yours are downright tortured and would lose points on a high school English class essay.   OP is asking about the way fluent speakers express the meaning he intends, and I give it in my answer.

Comment: @BadZen: That's ridiculous. Are you claiming that my final pair of examples (just OP's *exact* text, but choosing different nouns to place heavy stress on) ***don't*** carry two different meanings? Look again, and if you *still* don't get it, say them out loud!

Comment: The main point is that your examples are ungrammatical and no one should utter them.  "Z wasn't beaten by *even* X, let alone Y".    Can you at least try putting the things you write in a rudimentary grammar or usage checker before you recommend them to others, if you are unwilling to believe constructive criticism you receive here?

Comment: @BadZen: It has taken me many years, thinking about it and wondering whether or not what I had to say was [meaningful to even me, let alone anyone else](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to+even+me+let+alone%22) that might have the desire or need to pick this book up.

Comment: I'm going to reiterate my suggestion to you. Doing a Google or published work corpus search for a single instance of your use is a poor replacement for a grammar checker - human or machine - if uncertain. Especially if one doesn't read a sentence ahead to some abomination like "I am dedicating this book to all those souls who have wandered this earth [sic] and felt like I, that we are only an effect of others and that the mere thought of possibly becoming the cause, has never entered our minds." - whereupon a reasonably skilled reader would immediately proceed to find usage tips elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> <X> wasn't beaten by <Y>, *let alone* <Z>

The speaker simply means:  not only was <X> not beaten by <Y>, but also <X> was not beaten by <Z>.

In the speaker's opinion, <Y> is a much better opponent than <Z>, and if <Y> could not beat <X>, <Z> could not beat them either.

Compare:

A:  Can you loan me $100 until the end of the week?

B:  **I don't have twenty dollars, let alone a hundred!**

Comment: According to [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/let-alone), your sentence "<X> wasn't beaten by <Y>, let alone <Z>" emphasizes how unlikely _being beaten by <Z>_ was because _being beaten by <Y>_, which was far more likely, hadn't happened. So, <Z> should be inferior to <Y> in this case. What do you think?

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I must've been very tired when I wrote this.  Apologies for the error, I've edited above.  Thanks for the correction.